# Removendo elemento especifico de uma lista duplamente ligadas

Tags: c

Criei uma função para remover um elemento especifico de uma lista. Entretanto, o código apenas funciona direito quando se trata em relação ao primeiro elemento. A lógica é que quando o elemento chegou no qual diz respeito ele pega o anterior/próximo e limpa o elemento especifico da memória.

Aqui está  a função:

```
void remove_posicao(lista *cartas)
{
lista *aux = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
int i, pos;

aux = cartas -> prox;

if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Digite a posição que queira deletar: ");
scanf("%d", &pos);

for(i = 1; i <= pos; i++)
{
    if (i == pos)
    {
        cartas -> prox = aux -> prox;
        cartas -> ant = aux -> ant;
        free(aux);
    }
    else
    {
        aux = aux -> prox;
    }
}
}
```

Aqui está o resto do código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

struct No
{
int valor;
struct No *prox;
struct No *ant;
};

typedef struct No lista;

void inicializa(lista *cartas)
{
cartas -> prox = NULL;
cartas -> ant = NULL;
printf("Lista de cartas inicializadas\n\n");
}

void adiciona_inicio(lista *cartas)
{
lista *novo = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Digite uma carta para inserir no inicio: ");
scanf("%d", &novo -> valor);
lista *aux = cartas -> prox;
cartas -> prox = novo;
novo -> prox = aux;
novo -> ant = cartas;

if(aux != NULL)
{
    aux -> ant = novo;
}

}

void adiciona_fim(lista *cartas)
{
lista *novo = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));

if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}
printf("Digite uma carta para ser alocada no fim: ");
scanf("%d", &novo -> valor);
novo -> prox = NULL;

if(checa_lista(cartas))
{
    cartas -> prox = novo;
    novo -> ant = cartas;
}
else
{
    lista *aux = cartas -> prox;
    while(aux -> prox != NULL)
    {
        aux = aux -> prox;
        aux -> prox = novo;
        novo -> ant = aux;
    }
}
}

void adiciona_posicao(lista *cartas)
{
lista *aux = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
lista *novo = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
int i, pos;

aux = cartas -> prox;

if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Digite o valor que quer armazenar: ");
scanf("%d", &novo -> valor);
printf("Digite a posição que queira posicionar: ");
scanf("%d", &pos);

for(i = 1; i <= pos; i++)
{
    if (i == pos)
    {
        novo -> prox = aux;
        novo -> ant = aux->ant;
        aux -> ant -> prox = novo;


    }
    else
    {
        aux = aux->prox;
    }
}
}

void remove_inicio(lista *cartas)
{
lista *aux = cartas -> prox -> prox;
lista *head = cartas -> prox;
printf("Removendo o primeiro elemento do baralho \n");
cartas -> prox = cartas -> prox -> prox;
aux -> ant = cartas;
free(head);
}

void remove_posicao(lista *cartas)
{
lista *aux = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
int i, pos;

aux = cartas -> prox;

if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}

printf("Digite a posição que queira deletar: ");
scanf("%d", &pos);

for(i = 1; i <= pos; i++)
{
    if (i == pos)
    {
        cartas -> prox = aux -> prox;
        cartas -> ant = aux -> ant;
        free(aux);
    }
    else
    {
        aux = aux -> prox;
    }
}
}

void remove_fim(lista *cartas)
{
while(cartas -> prox -> prox != NULL)
{
    cartas = cartas -> prox;
}
free(cartas -> prox);
cartas -> prox = NULL;
printf("Removendo o último elemento do baralho! \n");
}

void limpa_lista(lista *cartas)
{
if(!checa_lista(cartas))
{
    lista *aux, *atual, *head;
    head = cartas;
    atual = cartas -> prox;
    while(atual -> prox != NULL)
    {
        aux = atual -> prox;
        free(atual);
        atual = aux;

    }
    if(atual -> prox == NULL)
    {
        head -> prox = NULL;
        free(atual);
    }
}
}

void mostra_lista(lista *cartas)
{
if(checa_lista(cartas))
{
    printf("Lista vazia\n");
    return ;
}
lista *aux = cartas -> prox;
while(aux != NULL)
{
    printf("Cartas = %d\n", aux -> valor);
    aux = aux -> prox;
}
}

void mostra_anterior(lista *cartas)
{
if(checa_lista(cartas))
{
    printf("Lista vazia\n");
    exit(1);
}

lista *aux = cartas;
printf("Cartas ");
while(aux -> prox != NULL)
{
    aux = aux -> prox;
    printf("-> %d", aux -> valor);
}
printf(" - ");

while(aux -> ant != NULL)
{
    printf("%d ->", aux -> valor);
    aux = aux -> ant;
}
printf("\n");
}

int checa_lista(lista *cartas)
 {
  if(cartas -> prox == NULL)
{
    return 1;
}
else
{
    return 0;
}
}

int tamanho_lista(lista *cartas)
{
int i = 0;
while(cartas -> prox != NULL)
{
    cartas = cartas -> prox;
    i++;
}
return i;

}

main()
{
setlocale(LC_ALL,"portuguese");
lista *cartas = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
int i;

if(!cartas)
{
    printf("Impossível alocar memória");
    exit(1);
}
else
{
    i = checa_lista(cartas);
    if(i == 1)
    {
        printf("Lista vazia\n");
    }
    else if (i == 0)
    {
        printf("Lista não vazia\n");
    }

    printf("Memória alocada\n");

    inicializa(cartas);
    adiciona_fim(cartas);
    adiciona_inicio(cartas);
    mostra_lista(cartas);
    mostra_anterior(cartas);
    adiciona_posicao(cartas);
    mostra_lista(cartas);
    remove_posicao(cartas);
    mostra_lista(cartas);
    /*remove_inicio(cartas);
    remove_fim(cartas);
    limpa_lista(cartas);*/
    i = tamanho_lista(cartas);
    free(cartas);
    return 0;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema está na lógica do que tem no `for` e tem maioritariamente a ver com o facto de estar a remover com base no `cartas` que representa o inicio e não o nó que vai andando no `for`. Para além disso também deve considerar no `for` o potencial do nó corrente a que chamou de `aux` de ser `NULL` e terminar caso isso aconteça.

Focando nesses pontos o `remove_posicao` ficaria assim:

```
void remove_posicao(lista *cartas) {
    lista *aux = cartas -> prox;
    int i, pos;

    if(!cartas) {
        printf("Impossível alocar memória");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Digite a posição que queira deletar: ");
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    for(i = 1; i <= pos && aux != NULL; i++) {
    //                       ^-- teste adicional para NULL
        if (i == pos) {
            lista *prox = aux -> prox; //captura primeiro o proximo do corrente
            aux -> prox -> ant = aux -> ant; // altera o anterior do próximo para o anterior
            aux -> ant -> prox = prox; //altera o proximo do anterior para o proximo
            free(aux); //remove o corrente
            aux = prox; //e avança para o próximo que tinha sido guardado no inicio
        } else {
            aux = aux -> prox;
        }
    }
}
```

Repare que troquei também o:

```
lista *aux = (lista *) malloc(sizeof(lista));
aux = cartas -> prox;
```

Pois está errado e estava a criar um nó adicional desnecessário que não ia ser utilizado, e ainda causava uma vazamento de memória pois não tinha o `free` correspondente.

Infelizmente, apesar de a lógica estar correta ainda não vai funcionar no seu código pois os ponteiros `ant` não estão a ser corretamente construídos, que é agora o seu próximo passo. Depure o código em relação às funções que inserem nós e observe os vários ponteiros `ant` que está a construir e perceba o ponto onde não os está a atribuir corretamente a fim de o corrigir e ficar com tudo a funcionar.

Comment: Entendi. Obrigado por ter me ajudado!